# If A is diagonalizable, and λ is a eigenvalue of A, is (A-λI) diagonalizable as well?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

question is as stated in the title. Is there also a way to prove it? Just curious, help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think $\lambda$ needs to be an eigenvalue. Incidentally, it is nice to have the question in the question.

Comment: uhm, its basically what it is, was just curious to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}$ is diagonal. Then
$$P(A - \lambda I)P^{-1} = PAP^{-1} - P(\lambda I)P^{-1} = PAP^{-1} - \lambda I$$
is a sum of diagonal matrices, thus also diagonal.

Comment: does it matter if λ is an eigen value or does it work for all cases?

Comment: As pointed out in the comments this works for any scalar $\lambda$ because any scalar multiple of the identity matrix commutes with all matrices.

Comment: Alright, thanks alot!